# A: My Custom StarterCharacter is not working! It can't hold gears and items, and won't sit down in Roblox

Tags: roblox

This problem is common among beginners, and its widely asked. There is a very easy way to fix this. Often times, the problem will cause your Custom character unable to interact with its surroundings, ex: Not being able to hold gears/items, sit down in vehicles or chairs and a LOT more.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have your StarterCharacter in the Starter Player module, you will notice a humanoid object in there with it. Delete the "Starter Humanoid" object and test it out! That will allow your custom character to sit, hold gears and do so much more. (The reason this works is because there is already a humanoid inside your starter character, the "StarterHumanoid" object is unneeded and causes problems with the humanoid already existing.